# ORACLE : Update query using two table with has relation

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I need to update the column data based on matching record found in both Table.
I want to update the record of NAME column from TABLE2

Following are the tables

```
 Table1
---------------
 Id | Name | color
 1  | abc  | red
 2  | def  | green
 3  | ghi  | blue


 Table2
---------------
 Id | Name | color |fiedId
 1  | abc  | red   | 1
 2  | def  | green | 1
 3  | ghi  | blue  | 2
```

Here table1 ID column is the Foreign Key in table2 as fieldId.

So, I want to update all the record which fall under this condition

```
table1.id = table2.fieldId
```

Comment: Update records in which table? and update what to what?

Comment: I want to update name in table 2

Comment: What's your attempt so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another option, using `MERGE`:

```
merge into table2 t2
using (select id, name from table1) x
on (t2.fieldid = x.id)
when matched then update set
  t2.name = x.name;
```

Or, for setting the name to 'xxx':

```
merge into table2 t2
using (select id from table1) x
on (t2.fiedid = x.id)
when matched then update set
  t2.name = 'xxx';
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just want an update like this:

```
update table2 t2
set    t2.name =
       ( select t1.name
         from   table1 t1
         where  t1.id = t2.fieldid )
```

Regarding the followup question:

> what if i want to set Name = "xxx" for all matching rows?

```
update table2 t2
set    t2.name = 'xxx'
where  t2.fieldid in
       ( select t1.id from table1 t1 )
```

or this can be written as:

```
update table2 t2
set    t2.name = 'xxx'
where  exists
       ( select null from table1 t1
         where  t1.id = t2.fieldid )
```

Comment: what if i want to set Name = "xxx" for all matching row?